# Why does javascript closure returns [Function (anonymous)]?

Tags: javascript, closures

Code from [medium,understand closures](https://medium.com/dailyjs/some-examples-to-help-understand-javascripts-closure-372e42fff94d)

```
function Person(name) {
    var secret = 'secret!';
    this.name = name
    this.setName = function(newName) { this.name = newName }
    this.setNameToFoo = function() { this.name = foo }
    this.getSecret = function() { return secret }
 }

 var a = new Person('Max');

 console.log(a.name);
 a.setName('Oliver')
 console.log(a.name);

 var foo = 'Foo';
 a.setNameToFoo()
 console.log(a.name); 

 console.log(a.getSecret);
```

Output

```
Max
Oliver
Foo
[Function (anonymous)]
```

Everything is OK,except the last one. It seems that local bindings is not visible.
 Why?

Comment: why you assign  this.getSecret = function , you just return your variable like this 
this.getSecret = secret ,:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last line you are not calling the function. It should be `console.log(a.getSecret());`

```js
function Person(name) {
    var secret = 'secret!';
    this.name = name
    this.setName = function(newName) { this.name = newName }
    this.setNameToFoo = function() { this.name = foo }
    this.getSecret = function() { return secret }
 }

 var a = new Person('Max');

 console.log(a.name);
 a.setName('Oliver')
 console.log(a.name);

 var foo = 'Foo';
 a.setNameToFoo()
 console.log(a.name); 

 console.log(a.getSecret());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're displaying the function itself in console.log, not its returning value.

Fix: Replace your last line with this one

```
console.log(a.getSecret());
```